# Formatting negative numbers dark red

Tags: excel

I have my cells formatted to have negative numbers in red with parentheses, but I'm trying to make the red a darker shade of red so it prints out better. I have the following formatting code currently and there doesn't seem to be any way to make the red darker:

```
$#,##0_);[Red]($#,##0)
```

Unfortunately I can't run any VBA code and conditional formatting would be a long process on this sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using conditional formatting or VBA, your cell format colors are restricted to just 8 colors:

[Black]
[Green]
[White]
[Blue]
[Magenta]
[Yellow]
[Cyan]
[Red]

(From [office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4))